# CSS: I can't see what is causing this underline

Tags: css

on [this site](http://test.doig.com.au/MHM/), there is a line underneath "Marketing Agency Fremantle".

[image]

I have used Chrome Code Inspector but cannot find what is causing this.

I want to remove the line. Thanks.

Comment: It's a `h2` `::after` [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `:after` pseudo element for `h2` is causing the underline.

Answer (score 1):

It's this CSS rule:

```
body.home h2::after {
    content: '';
    width: 60px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #4a2e69;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

You can erase it or (if you can't do that) add the following to set height to 0 and make it invisible that way:

```
body.home h2::after {
        height: 1px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is :after in your h2 tag

[image]